# Rotating color change, something like the Edge lighting Android

Tags: javascript, android, animation, colors

I am trying to animate a rotating colour change around the border of my background something like the one shown in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmxA1qvZlxs

Have been searching for clues for a long time but have yet to find anything useful.

I am using ValueAnimator for the border color transition but am at a lost for making it 'spin' or 'rotate' as in the video. My Code as Follow:

```js
ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
        anim.setIntValues(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"));
        anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                bgShape.setStroke(10, (Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        anim.setDuration(10000);
        anim.setRepeatCount(1);
        anim.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(10));
        anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        anim.start();
```

Anyone with ideas or work around this problem that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess you need to specify new value of the color as well in `onAnimationUpdate`?  `anim.setIntValues(Color.parseColor(NEW_RANDOM_VALUE_OF_COLOR_HERE), Color.parseColor(NEW_RANDOM_VALUE_OF_COLOR_HERE))`

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but it doesn't give me the rotation effect. Thanks for your input.

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain CSS for this if using android WebView is ok for you. Something like this could achieve this kind of effect:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#mobile {
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#mobile:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 165px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#background {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 310px;
  height: 540px;
  border-radius: 50px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#foreground {
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  width: 300px;
  height: 530px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#rotating-box {
  border-radius: 50px;
  min-width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    red,
    orange,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
    indigo,
    violet
  );
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mobile">
      <div id="background">
        <div id="rotating-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="foreground"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```